# React-Bootstrap Progress Bar does not update with state change

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, progress-bar, react-bootstrap

I have an issue with not being able to correctly set up the React-Bootstrap Progress Bar. It should update its "now" value based on the component's state variable . I am calling an image processing function, which updates the component state with 25,50,75,100 as it processes the image (verified via console.log that this works). However, the Progress Bar only jumps from 0 to 100. How can I make the Progress Bar update its "now" value from the state?

The code is below, thank you for your ideas of how to solve this :)

```
class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { uploadProgress: null };
    }

    setUploadProgress = (progress) => {
      this.setState({uploadProgress: progress});
    }

    render() {
    return (
    <ProgressBar now={this.state.uploadProgress} label={this.state.uploadProgress} />
    )
    }
}

export default RegistrationForm;
```

imageProcessing.js: this file is linked to the RegistrationForm and calls the setUploadProgress function on the registration form. When I'm console.logging the state on the RegistrationForm component, the state gets updated immediately, but the progress bar rather jumps from 0 to 100.. I'm not sure whether it's an issue of incorrectly binding the context or incorrectly referencing the setUploadProgress method of Registration Form. The whole image processing takes about 3-4 seconds on my computer, so there should be plenty of time for the progress bar to change according to state change.

*imageProcessing.js*

```
var Jimp = require('jimp');

function Progress(context) {
    this.currentProgress = 0;
    this.setUploadProgress = context.setUploadProgress;
  }

export default async function ProcessImage (image, context) {
let progressBar = new Progress(context);
let image = await Jimp.read(imageUrl);
progressBar.setUploadProgress(10);
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's too fast to see incremental changes. Try [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-poitras-8j5fm?file=/src/App.js) and play with interval delay to check how this works.

Comment: Hi Ramil, thanks a lot for your input - I do not think it's too fast, the imageProcessing function takes about 3-4 seconds. I updated the code above to include the imageProcessing function itself, maybe the issue is there?

Comment: I see the function `setUploadProgress` is called just once, after `Jimp.read` is finished (because `await Jimp.read(..)`). If there's no more call of `setUploadProgress`, this is why the progress bar changes only once.

Comment: This is just a snippet of the code, I'm actually calling progressBar.setUploadProgress multiple times in the full version.. It's an issue with the state not being correctly propagated to the progress bar, but I can't find where it's coming from

Comment: Probably without the full code it's impossible to answer because the same code works well in the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-poitras-8j5fm?file=/src/App.js).